# Regex match if a string has length 2 and contains 1 letter and 1 number

Tags: c#, regex

Guys I hate Regex and I suck at writing.

I have a string that is space separated and contains several codes that I need to pull out.  Each code is marked by beginning with a capital letter and ending with a number.  The code is only two digits.

I'm trying to create an array of strings from the initial string and I can't get the regular expression right.

Here is what I have

```
String[] test = Regex.Split(originalText, "([a-zA-Z0-9]{2})");
```

I also tried:

```
String[] test = Regex.Split(originalText, "([A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})");
```

I don't have any experience with Regex as I try to avoid writing them whenever possible.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Example input:

AA2410 F7 A4 Y7 B7 A 0715 0836 E0.M80

I need to pull out F7, A4, B7.  E0 should be ignored.

Comment: can you show an example input and output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to collect the results, not split on them, right?

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\b[A-Z][0-9]\b");
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

should do this. The `\b`s are word boundaries, making sure that only entire strings (like `A1`) are extracted, not substrings (like the `A1` in `TWA101`).

If you also need to exclude "words" with non-word characters in them (like `E0.M80` in your comment), you need to define your own word boundary, for example:

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<=^|\s)[A-Z][0-9](?=\s|$)");
```

Now `A1` only matches when surrounded by whitespace (or start/end-of-string positions).

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=  # Assert that we can match the following before the current position:
 ^    # Start of string
|     # or
 \s   # whitespace.
) 
[A-Z] # Match an uppercase ASCII letter
[0-9] # Match an ASCII digit
(?=   # Assert that we can match the following after the current position:
 \s   # Whitespace
|     # or
 $    # end of string.
)
```

If you also need to find non-ASCII letters/digits, you can use

```
\p{Lu}\p{N}
```

instead of `[A-Z][0-9]`. This finds all uppercase Unicode letters and Unicode digits (like `Ä٣`), but I guess that's not really what you're after, is it?

Comment: This works but it does not care about length.  An input of E0.M80 is captured when it should not be.  Hm.

Comment: There is a word boundary between the `0` and  the `.`, so you need to define exactly what a "word" is in your context. I'm assuming non-whitespace characters and will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That did it.  Now I just have to learn why it did it.

Comment: @Chase: I didn't have time just now to write an explanation, but now I've written one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  That helps a lot.  As does this cheat sheet that I found http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that each code looks like "A00"?

Then this is the regex:

`"[A-Z][0-9][0-9]"`

Very simple... By the way, there's no point writing `{1}` in a regex. `[0-9]{1}` means "match exactly one digit, which is exactly like writing `[0-9]`.

Don't give up, simple regexes make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok:

```
String[] all_codes = Regex.Split(originalText, @"\b[A-Z]\d\b");
```

It gives you an array with all code starting with a capital letter followed by a digit, separated by an kind of word boundary (site space etc.)